# SQL finding the maximum of all averaged results

Tags: sql, max, average

I have the relation instructor(ID, name, dept_name, salary).

How would I go about finding the name of the department with the highest average salary?

Comment: Forgot to mention, this is in Oracle SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will this do the trick?

```
select top 1 id, name, avg (salary)
from instructor
group by id, name
order by avg (salary) desc
```

Comment: No. I can get the averages of all the department's by using:

select dept_name, avg(salary)
from instructor
group by dept_name

But I can't select the highest average salary department from there.

Comment: You can "order by desc avg(salary) limit 1" to see the highest.

Comment: select dept_name 
from instructor
group by dept_name
order by avg(salary) desc limit 1

    Gives me an error "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL, however trying to use having rownum=1 still results in the same error.

Comment: top 1 is TSQL; limit 1 is used in MySQL. My earlier comment with "having rownum=1" is incorrect, see http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html for the full details. If you are using Oracle, you will have to do something like: select * from (select dept_name, avg(salary) from instructor group by  dept_name order by avg(salary)) where ROWNUM = 1

Answer (score 3):

looks like a job for the [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_having.asp) clause

Comment: Something along the lines of:
having avg(salary) > 

?

Answer (score 0):

Given the <kbd>homework</kbd> tag, I won't spell it out for you, but you want to look into the `AVG` function and the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: It is indeed homework, my mistake for not tagging it as such, but I've been working on it quite a bit and just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 dept_name, avg(salary) as AvgSalary
from instructor
group by dept_name
order by AvgSalary desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you both if two deparments have the same average salary, use rownum=1 if this is not needed.

`with averages as  (select dept_name,avg(salary) aver from instructor group by dept_name)`
`select dept_name`
`from averages`
`where  aver = (select max(aver) from averages)`